# What is the difference between 끝나다 and 끝내다?

Tags: meaning

I saw both verbs here and there, and both seems to mean "to finish" (according to Google translate).

What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

끝나다 is an intransitive verb meaning that something has ended 'of its own accord' - e.g. 영화가 끝났다 - the film has finished.

끝내다 is a transitive verb meaning someone has finished something - e.g. 그 일을 끝냈다 - (someone) finished that job.

This is a somewhat general pattern when using -나다 and -내다: -나다 is used when something happens on its own, or we aren't talking about the cause; -내다 is used when something is made to happen.

Comment: To make sure I understood: 일이 끝나요 - The work is finished.
일을 끝내요 - Someone [probably me, or someone I am speaking about, depending on the context] finished the work.

Comment: @Taladris that's about right - your examples don't use '았' to show the past tense, but that might be implied. While 여섯 시에 일이 끝나요 would literally mean "work finishes at 6 o'clock", if you are talking about your work it might still be translated as *I finish work at 6* as that's more natural English.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this rule can be helpful: (1) 이/가 + 끝났다, (2) 을/를 + 끝냈다.

Add: 내가 끝냈다 is a correct sentence, because actually the sentence has an implied, invisible object. For example, 내가 (공사를) 끝냈다.

Comment: Please elaborate on how the rule works with more usage examples. We don't encourage one-liner answers.

Comment: This is a good additional point - you could link it to the way that a sentence with '이/가' but no 을/를 is likely to contain an intransitive verb, while a sentence with 을/를 would have a transitive verb. However I think you *can* still say '내가 끝냈다', meaning I finished (it), with an implied object.

Comment: @topomorto Thanks for your comment. I will add the information about implied objects.

Comment: Do let me know when you edit your answer with more details.